# How to specify a reverse landscape layout in android?

Tags: android

My application supports both landscape and reverse landscape. When the user rotates to reverse landscape Android shows my same layout. I would like to provide a reverse landscape layout to be used in reverse landscape orientation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem like this is possible.

The [resource qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) only distinguish between port(trait) and land(scape) and also if you'd handle configuration changes programmatically, `Configuration.ORIENATION` only can be `Configuration.PORTRAIT` or `Configuration.LANDSCAPE`. No 'reverse landscape' there...